# RelayJS error Flowtype

Tags: flowtype, relayjs

I install RelayJS then encountered this error.

[image]

.flowconfig is default of react-native-cli

Comment: Please post your flowconfig.  You may need to exclude node_modules and/or install `flow-typed` to provide flow module definitions.

Comment: .flowconfig is default of react-native-cli

Comment: Please post the config, it may be different per version. Also, what about the other suggestions?